# Processing PHP scripts from within C#

Tags: c#, php, .net, winforms

I'm not sure if this has even been done before, but what I am trying to accomplish can't be explained in any great detail, but basically, what I am trying to do is Process PHP scripts from within my C# Windows Forms Application.

I have already created a HTTP server, which works just fine. But now I need to be able to process PHP scripts aswell. We're working on a new privatised language over here, purely for learning and fun.

(Just a little background, not completely related):

We are now able to create a webpage like so:

```
Using System.Core,
System.Http,
System.Graphics and System.IO;

    protected void -> Webpage(object homepage)
    {
        // Set Webpage properties.
        homepage.Name = "Home";
        homepage.Size = new Size(960[px], 100[%]);
        homepage.Alignment = new AlignmentType.Vertical;
        homepage.Alignment = new AlignmentType.Horizontal;

        // This is a comment.
        // Create objects to be rendered on the page.

        Text text = new Text();
        FormElements formElements = new FormElements();

        private void -> Webpage.Load(object homepage)
        {
            text.Text = "Please enter your name below:";

            text.Style = new Style(
                Alignment = new AlignmentType.Horizontal,
                Alignment = new AlignmentType.ManualAlignment(15[Y, px]),

                Font = new Font(
                    Font.Family("Arial"),
                    Font.Size = new Size(9[pt], LineHeight(4[px])),
                    Font.Color = new Color.FromArgb(15, 15, 15))
            );

            formElements.CreateElements(TextField["textField"], SubmitButton["submitButton"], Form["form"]);

            textField.Name = "name";
            submitButton.Name = "submit";

            form.Encapsulate(name, submit);

            form.Alignment = new AlignmentType.RelativeTo(text.Bottom);

            Elements[] elements = new Elements[]
            {
                text, form;
            };

            homepage.Display.Element.ElementCollection(elements);
        }

        private void -> Webpage.FormSubmission(object form)
        {
            form.Element(name).OmitSpecialCharacters();

            if(form.Value is not Empty)
            {
                text.Text = "Hello, " + form.Element(name).Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The above sample demonstrates the ability to create a whole webpage, style it, and process form input in a nice, clean way. However, we've come to a complete dead end (trying to support PHP) and we do not wish to delve too far into server-side languages (lack of experience in that area is the main reason), so we would like to be able to "support" PHP scripts from within our WinForms app.

Anyone know of any way to process PHP scripts from within a C# winforms app?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use an `HttpWebRequest`, and request the url to the `PHP` page like you would to run the `PHP` page in your browser.

See here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple http server that supports PHP:
[MiniHttpd: an HTTP web server library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/minihttpd.aspx)

And here is [Phalanger - The PHP Language Compiler for the .NET Framework](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Hmmm, so using MiniHttpd as our server, we could pass our *.jml files with the code above (in my question) and also php scripts inside the jml file to the server and it would treat the php code normally?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you have to pass a *pure* php file for MiniHttpd to work. Otherwise you have to make use/tweak either the http support in MiniHttpd, or make use of Phalanger. Why don't you give it a try to see the results?